# RegEx - Or operator

Tags: python, regex

I am executing this.

```
print(re.findall(r'(<OR|<PP).*>', '<OR first><PP second><OR third>'))
```

Expected:

```
['<OR first>', '<PP second>', '<OR third>']
```

Actual:

```
['<OR']
```

Does any body know how I can achieve the expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'(?:<OR|<PP)[^>]*>', '<OR first><PP second><OR third>'))
```

Note that

- findall only returns captured groups if there are any, otherwise the full match
- `.*` matches greedily, so your pattern matches the whole string

Comment: Thank you Sebastian Proske!

Comment: Instead of `[^>]*` you can also use `.*?` which is non-greedy equivalent of `.*`